# Android mobile app 'cold' wallets that allow cold signing TXs, saving the file to an SD card and loading updates into it by file?

Tags: cold-storage, monerujo, mobile-wallet

Can anyone suggest Android mobile app cold wallets that allow cold signing TXs, saving the file to a micro SD card and loading updates into it by file in said SD card? I would be doing this on a disconnected/non-networked Android smartphone. I looked at the Monerujo website but no mention there on this subject.